# ( was unexpected at this time batch

Tags: batch-file

When running this in batch, I get a "( was unexpected at this time" error. Why? I have quotes surrounding both the variable and what the variable is equal to. There's a space after y, and then parentheses.

```
echo Would you like to update and restore to the latest OS? (-l -e) (Y/N)

set /p latestOS= ""

if "%latestOS%"=="y" (

echo Restoring...make sure your device is plugged in!

\idevicerestore\idevicerestore -l -e

echo Done.

timeout /t 2 /nobreak > NUL

) else (

    echo Okay. Where is the IPSW located? EX: C:\memez.ipsw

    set /p IPSWlocid= ""

    echo Alright. Is it a custom IPSW? Note that the device must be vulnerable to limera1n. (-c) (Y/N)

    set /p IPSWiscustomid= ""

    rem more stuff soon

)

:menu
```

It fails at the if latestOS line.

Comment: Stil failed, but got a different error afterwards. Apparently the parentheses in the first echo line messed it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a code block (that's code inside of parentheses), batch considers the first unescaped `)` to be the end of that block, regardless of where in the code block it is located.

The second `echo` inside of your `else` block is breaking your code. To fix it, use `^` to escape both of the `)`s.

```
echo Alright. Is it a custom IPSW? Note that the device must be vulnerable to limera1n. (-c^) (Y/N^)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems with your code, including the use of parentheses in the first `echo` statement that aren't quoted or escaped, and a space after the `=` sign in your `set /p` line. Your code can be made much simpler, though. I'm not going to address it all, but here are some relevant changes that can help.

```
@echo off
set /p latestOS="Would you like to update and restore to the latest OS? (-l -e) (Y/N): "

if "%latestOS%"=="y" (
  echo You chose Yes
) else (
  echo You chose No
)
```